# Where does 1.3606 approximation ratio come from for vertex cover approximation?

Tags: approximation, vertex-cover

I was watching a [coursera video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/approximation-algorithms/lecture/uXroX/an-approximation-algorithm-for-vertex-cover) on Approximation algorithms and I understood the 2-approximation algorithm.

[image: slide]

Later, the professor asks if we can do any better. The lecturer went on to say that computing `1.3606` approximation is NP-hard in the following words at 8:14.

Here's the transcript for that part.

> Actually, what is also interesting to note is that okay, maybe we still have some hope that we can get a little bit below two for the approximation ratio, but as the second staple that you see here shows is that it's not possible to get really close to one, but it's impossible to get something better than roughly 1.3, because already computing a 1.36 approximation as you see here, already that problem is NP-hard.

1. How does he skip from *nobody found a 1.99-approximation algorithm*
   to getting `1.3606` is NP-Hard?
2. Where does `1.3606` come from?

Comment: Recently improved to $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Meaning that it has been shown that it is NP-hard to find a $\sqrt{2}$ approximation ratio?

Comment: Right. The truth is probably 2.

Comment: A bit confused now that you have written $2$ and not $\sqrt{2}$. You mean that it is more likely that we can't beat $2$ as the approximation ratio?

Comment: It’s known that you can’t do better than $\sqrt 2$, and it’s conjectured that you can’t do better than 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that nobody found a $1.99$ approximation doesn't necessarily mean that the problem of finding one is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard (e.g., it might be the case that that $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$ and a polynomial-time $1.99$-approximation algorithm exists, we are just unaware of it).

Additionally, we can prove that finding a $1.3606$-approximation is a $\mathsf{NP}$-hard problem, i.e., if $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$ no $1.3606$-approximation algorithm exists. This is not a direct consequence of the previous fact, but a separate result by Irit Dinur and Samuel Safra. The details can be found [here](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v162-n1-p08.pdf).

Comment: So it could be possible to go lower than 1.3606?

Comment: From what we know, we cannot rule out the existence of a polynomial-time $x$-approximation algorithm with $x<1.3606$. However that would imply  $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$.

Comment: Now if $P=NP$, would the approximation ration even if it is $x>1$ be of any use because we would be able to solve vertex cover in polynomial time?

Comment: It could be useful depending on the time complexity of said algorithm. for example if we don't know a better exact algorithm than in $\Omega(n^{100})$, but know a $1.3$-approximation algorithm in $O(n^2)$.

Comment: A recent result improves the hardness of approximation to $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, thanks for pointing this out! [Here](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2018/006/revision/2/download) is the relevant paper (see, in particular, the discussion of page 6).